Inventory With multiple items unit
I'm working on designing a database in MS Access, but I'm having trouble with handling products that come in different units. I would greatly appreciate any guidance on the correct way to design this. Here is the design I have come up with so far:
there is a similar post like this but unfortunately i couldn't get it fully to make my database work thats why I repost it

I have attempted to create a separate table for product units and a junction table to establish a many-to-many relationship with the product table. However, I am not confident that this is the correct approach. Additionally, I am unsure how to handle purchases of this item in different units.

First: decide for your products what a useful standard unit would be where all other units are based on. This could be liters or kg or something else. Create a table e. g. ProductUnits. Fields: ProductID, Unit, multiplicator and additional infos regarding this combination of product and unit, e. g. EAN-Code, is it the standard unit (yes/no) or is this unit active (yes/no). The multiplicator is used to convert your actual value to your base unit.
Now you can use the unit in your purchasing form as well as in an selling form. The purchasing price is comparable over all units because you have the factor.
Tip: save prices (except price of invoices) always in a separate table with validity date as they will change over time.
